# selecting all cells between two string in a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I posted question previously as "using “.between” for string values not working in python" and I was not clear enough, but I could not edit, so I am reposting with clarity here.

I have a Data Frame. In [0,61] I have string. In [0,69] I have a string. I want to slice all the data in cells [0,62:68] between these two and merge them, and paste the result into [1,61]. Subsequently, [0,62:68] will be blank, but that is not important.

However, I have several hundred documents, and I want to write a script that executes on all of them. The strings in [0,61] and [0,69] are always present in all the documents, but along different locations in that column. So I tried using:

For_Paste = df[0][df[0].between('DESCRIPTION OF WORK / STATEMENT OF WORK', 'ADDITIONAL REQUIREMENTS / SUPPORTING DOCUMENTATION', inclusive = False)]

But the output I get is: Series([], Name: 0, dtype: object)

I was expecting a list or array with the desired data that I could merge and paste. Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuBD7.png)

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation for df.between()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html). What you are doing with df[0].between(...) is comparing strings with one another, selecting all rows in which the string s satisfy s >= left and s <= right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to select the rows between two indices (say `idx_start` and `idx_end`), excluding these two rows) on column `col` of the dataframe `df`, you will want to use

```
df.loc[idx_start + 1 : idx_end, col]
```

To find the first index matching a string `s`, use

```
idx = df.index[df[col] == s][0]
```

So for your case, to return a Series of the rows between these two indices, try the following:

```
start_string = 'DESCRIPTION OF WORK / STATEMENT OF WORK'
end_string = 'ADDITIONAL REQUIREMENTS / SUPPORTING DOCUMENTATION'
idx_start = df.index[df[0] == start_string][0]
idx_end = df.index[df[0] == end_string][0]
For_Paste = df.loc[idx_start + 1 : idx_end, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you Fabian. I get an "IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0" for line four. I tried trouble shooting it, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: This means that df.[0] == end_string is False for all rows. So make sure the end_string is exactly as in the dataframe. The string may be slightly different (e.g. a space missing or too much etc.)

Comment: That is exactly what I ended up doing. I executed a single line of code to return: the location of 'ADDITIONAL REQUIREMENTS / SUPPORTING DOCUMENTATION' and got nothing. So I used this code to prevent truncation of data inside of cells: pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1) and that revealed I left out 'Requirements' from the second string. Works great now. Thanks!